# PHP SELECT from two tables

Tags: php, mysql, database, select, pdo

here is my database:

```
table 1: dog
   column 1: email
   column 2: password

table 2: cat
   column 1: email
   column 2: password
```

i want to check if a string or data already exists or not in a column from two databases:

```
//check if email exists in either dog or cat.
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT email FROM dog AND cat WHERE email = :email");
$stmt->bindParam(':email', $email);
$stmt->execute();
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

//if the email exists in either dog or cat, echo the "taken" message below
if($row['email'] == $email) {
   echo "sorry, the email is taken already!";
}
```

but it is not working for me. how can i make it work?

Comment: in a column of both is OR not AND

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The SQL syntax is not valid.

We can test the return from `prepare`, and if it's FALSE, then we know an error occurred.

Here's an example:

```
  //check if email exists in either dog or cat.
  $sql = "SELECT 'dog' AS src, d.email FROM dog d WHERE d.email = :demail
           UNION ALL
          SELECT 'cat' AS src, c.email FROM cat c WHERE c.email = :cemail";

  if ($stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql)) {
      $stmt->bindParam(':demail', $email);
      $stmt->bindParam(':cemail', $email);
      $stmt->execute();
     ...

  } else {
      // handle error condition
  }
```

Comment: I do believe you either want to remove the quotes from around the `dog` and `cat` columns or use ticks `\``.

Comment: @Fred-ii-:  The usage of single quotes around the string literals is what I intended. The `src` column is intended to be a discriminator column... to identify (on each row returned) which SELECT returned which row.  Perhaps my choice of literal values (`'dog'` and `'cat'`) was confusing. It's not necessary to return the `src` column at all, but its a pattern we use frequently with UNION ALL queries.

Comment: TBH; I wasn't 100% sure about the quotes. You may be right though and do believe I have seen that type of syntax before. If the OP says there was an error, then the quotes might need to be removed.

Answer (score 0):

The `AND` operator is used for boolean expressions in the `WHERE` clause and in a `JOIN` condition.

You're looking for [`UNION`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html). It combines results from queries that have similar columns.

```
SELECT email
FROM dog
WHERE email = :email
UNION
SELECT email
FROM cat
WHERE email = :email
```